# Safe way to delete rows

Tags: php, pdo, sql-server-2005

I am writing code to delete a row based on ID from a SQL Server database.  I want to make sure my code is safe from accidentally deleting everything or deleting something other than what it should.  My code at the moment is as follows...

```
$st = $conn->prepare("if (select count(*) from sometable where id = :id)  = 1 
    delete from sometable where id = :id");

$st->bindParam(':id',$id);  

$st->execute();
```

Is this a safe way to delete a single row without accidentally deleting everything?   Is there a better, known best-practices way to do it?

**Edit:** I am getting an error `COUNT field incorrect or syntax error` when testing this code.

I have changed my code accordingly to resolve this (I was hoping I could refer to the same field more than once and bind it once but apparently not)

```
$st = $conn->prepare("if (select count(*) from sometable where id = ?)  = 1 
delete from sometable where id = ?");

$st->execute(array($id,$id));
```

(Might as well use my question to troubleshoot since stackoverflow won't let me delete it)

Comment: As long as you have `where id = :id` in the query (and you actually pass the correct ID), `delete from sometable where id = :id` is enough.

Comment: Assuming the `id` is unique, the `delete` line is all you need. It will delete 1 row at most and 0 if it does not exist.

Comment: seems another candidate for code review or db exchange

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - I think this is close enough to stay here (in my humble opinion, that is)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Code Review should be in the standard off-topic migration list...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson "border line" ;-)

Comment: @jeroen ^ ^ ^ ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Not arguing against that, though :-)

Comment: *"Is this a safe way to delete a single row without accidentally deleting everything? Is there a better, known best-practices way to do it?"* - If it works; sure.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson well... at this point, the question's unclear. If they're paranoid about using a prepared statement, then they should test it out first before posting, IMHO.

Comment: Never delete! Flag every row with a enabled boolean and just toggle it ;) That way you keep EVERYTHING ever entered in your database. (being devils advocate here)

Comment: This questions is based more in insecurity than anything else.

Comment: *"where id = :id"* - just as long as there aren't id's bearing the same value... then you're good to go. I have seen some using same id's for God knows what/why.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Well, a sub table thats many to one, you would find many rows with the same 'parent' id. :)

Comment: @IncredibleHat right you are.

Comment: *"Never delete! etc"* - @IncredibleHat - That's debatable but not crazy ;-)

Comment: @IncredibleHat addendum to my last comment reply; well... if they have what could be parent id's, then they'd have to delete everything. However, the question is unclear in that respect and given what they posted. There's no schema and is missing detail. So I voted to close as unclear.

Comment: While everybody was busy discussing, Jay earned 20 pts

Comment: True @FunkFortyNiner , because a boss was once "can we recover a deleted order?"  (years after the fact) ... and I was like ... uhhhh... so yeah, had to re-rig the system to use toggles to 'delete' instead of actually 'delete'. But he still wanted to recover the deletes stuff *sigh*. As for parent ids... correct you are (it was unclear). Normally when I do relational tables, I STILL have a item id for whatever is paired to the parent.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I never miss a beat ;-) *heh*

Comment: *tosses another +10 at Jay*

Comment: @IncredibleHat and that's where experience comes in handy. Well.. they can always have another table for deleted stuff also, but that's just another way to be pals with the devil too ;-) as per your *"(being devils advocate here)"* - lol

Comment: @IncredibleHat I also agree with the non-deletion deletion thing just because a boss wanted to recover something many moons after the event(s) had passed. I suppose it depends on the data and the schema, none of which we have here. Assumptions had to be made for the answer.

Comment: These comments are soo gonna be removed by moderator :p

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I don't think so; it's all valuable information, least most of them anyway. And they should not be deleted neither.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Well, I haven't actually read all those but you said it's valuable. I trust you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a safe way to delete a single row without accidentally deleting everything?

Yes, as long as your ID's are unique for each row.

> Is there a better, known best-practices way to do it?

No.